# Twilio: 'Send to Flex' without using widget in Studio Flow?

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml, twilio-programmable-voice, twilio-studio, twilio-flex

I have a solution using Twilio's **Programmable Voice** APIs and some automation.

I would like to integrate this with **Twilio Flex** to handover to a human agent, however the only way I have found so far to handover a call into Flex, is with the 'Send to Flex' widget in a **Twilio Studio Flow**.

**Is this the only way to send a call into Flex?**

Do I HAVE TO use a Studio Flow?
Is there a TwiML equivalent to the 'Send to Flex' widget? (I can't find it)

A (small) cost is incurred to use a Studio Flow, so to have to employ a Flow just for this seems a bit rich.

Thanks for reading, and hopeful for answers.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `Enqueue` TwiML Verb.

[TwiML™ Voice:](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/enqueue)

> workflowSid The 'workflowSid' attribute tells Twilio to create a new
> TaskRouter Task to represent this call and specifies the ID of the
> desired Workflow to handle it.

Comment: Thanks Alan. Does indeed seem to work if I use the Workflow SID from a Flex Workflow (SID starting with WW... it seems). Thanks!